# ActiveCollab 5 Update not working with nginx (HTTP 403 Forbidden)

Tags: nginx, activecollab

We are trying to **update** a **self-hosted** ActiveCollab installation.

The current version is 4 (latest **4.12.23**) and we have access to v**5.0.100**. We followed the [upgrade instructions](https://activecollab.com/help/books/self-hosted/upgrade) and [v5 installations instructions](https://activecollab.com/help/books/self-hosted/installation#s-installation), but with no avail so far. When using a subfolder of the running v4 installation, accessing this subfolder (or `/public`) returns a HTTP Code of 403. The entry in the `nginx` log is:

> 2017/10/17 08:12:26 [error] 4788#4788: *42 directory index of "/var/www/activecollab/activecollab-5/public/" is forbidden, client: xxx.xx.xxx.xx, server: ac.example.org, request: "GET /activecollab-5/public/ HTTP/1.1", host: "ac.example.org"`

We would appreciate to see a working full (!) `nginx` config, so we could further evaluate the v5 update for our use-cases and perhaps buy a new update subscription ;).

Comment: Your nginx host is not correctly configure. When it is properly set, it shows the installer instead of 403. Double check your configuration prior to continuing with the upgrade (we have more info here: https://activecollab.com/help/books/self-hosted/installation)

Comment: Thank you for your answer! This is the guide I followed along. The old v4 installation was working fine, so I assume there is changes in the nginx config required, but I can't find full documentation (or a working example of it) anywhere.